# sed replace command

Tags: shell, sed

I want to uncomment one of these two statements as per condition:

```
#export CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:$TOMCAT_INSTALL_LOCATION/$APACHE_TOMCAT_VERSION/lib/oi-mule-libs/usage/injector.jar"

#export CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:$TOMCAT_INSTALL_LOCATION/$APACHE_TOMCAT_VERSION/lib/agents/cl-proxy-agent.jar"
```

I used following sed command:

```
 #sed -i 's/#export CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:$TOMCAT_INSTALL_LOCATION/$APACHE_TOMCAT_VERSION/lib/oi-mule-libs/usage/injector.jar"/export CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:$TOMCAT_INSTALL_LOCATION/$APACHE_TOMCAT_VERSION/lib/oi-mule-libs/usage/injector.jar"/' $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/init-script.sh
```

I got following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unknown option to `s'
```

Why did I get this error?

How could I achieve my purpose by modifying above command?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your delimeters to the sed command. Your delimiter is '/' which also appers in your pattern and that gives an error. Try this:

```
sed 's:<pattern to be replaced>:<replacement pattern>:g'
```

Here g is for global, s for substitute. You can use any other delimiter not appearing in your pattern, I have used colon ':' in the example

Answer (score 0):

You need to either escape slash characters with backslashes or use another character as a delimiter for the "s"ubstitute command (as pointed out  by sleeping_dragon)
With that in mind:

```
 sed -e s/^#(.*\/injector.jar.*)/\1/ -e s/^#(.*\/cl-proxy-agent.jar.*)/\1/ $my_file
```

making the regular expression in round brackets as unique as required to identify the exact string you need uncommenting.